# Find function definition in C++

Tags: c++, makefile

I have a C++ project on remote machine which compiles with makefile. No ide available, only vim and commandline. I found a function in the sourcecode and want to find its definition. How can I do that without manually looking all -I directories and source files? 
Is it possible to stop makefile after preprocessing phase and lookup in the resulting sourcefiles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to use grep (with find to get results very fast) like this:

```
find srcDir -name "*.c" -o -name "*.cpp" -print0 | xargs -0 grep "functionName"
```

The Makefile based solution is to change the linking so you ask for a verbose location of a function definition like this (if you use GCC) (you can also do that on the command line with "make LDFLAGS=...seebelow...")

```
# In your makefile, locate this:
LDFLAGS:= ...
# Replace by this
LDFLAGS:= -Wl,--trace-symbol=functionName
```

This results in:

```
$ gcc -o test main.o -Wl,--trace-symbol=main
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/crt1.o: reference to main
main.o: definition of main
```

This solution is useful if you have plenty of similar function name, and you actually want the one that's used in the final binary.

Answer (score 5):

You can use ctag and cscop to browse the code on vi.
If you are not comfortable with that then use a

```
grep -rn funtion_name ./
```

in the home dir of the source code, and manually look for the definition in the result set.

Comment: `ctags` is great for this. For instance, I ran `ctags -R --c++-kinds=+p --fields=+iaS --extra=+q /usr/include` to find all function definitions for my entire C++ project and standard library. Super useful for finding why some std lib functions were missing on another system.

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently developing under Visual Studios, but I still use
vim as my editor, and the Unix took kit (from CygWin) for just
about everything but compiling and debugging.

First, of course, if you can't easily deduce where the function
is declared and defined, there's something wrong with you source
structure and naming conventions.  Regretfully, most of us don't
have full control, and the case does really occur.

If the function is in your source tree, you can search using
`grep`, possibly with `find` to find the files to search.  If
it's not (which is often the case), you can generally output the
preprocessor results by invoking the compiler with the `-E`
option.  You may want to define a target in `make` for this.
On the other hand, the *only* compiler options you need here are
the `-I` and `-D` options; if they aren't too complex, you can
just invoke the compiler by hand.  (Or you might consider
defining an environment variable with them, so you can easily
invoke the compiler by hand.)  `-E` will usually output to
standard out, so you'll have to redirect the output to a file.
After than, it's easy to find the file where the function was
*declared*, since the preprocessor output contains #line
directives with the file name.  As to where it is defined... if
it's third party software, you may not even have the definition;
vendors often furnish just headers and a library.

Answer (score 1):

You can use several plugins for vin to do code browsing.

A friend of mine created its own plugin : [lh-tags](https://code.google.com/p/lh-vim/source/browse/#svn/tags)  and he developed an indexer for vim for C and C++ base code  with clang : [CLIC](https://github.com/LucHermitte/clang_indexer) (with its own helper package, [vim-clang](https://github.com/LucHermitte/vim-clang))